# What is gradient correlation?

Tags: correlation, image-processing, definition

I came to cross a type of correlation that I haven't heard before --- what is gradient correlation? Does the gradient correlation function range from 0 to 1 just like the regular Pearson's correlation? Like the Pearson's correlation, does higher gradient correlation indicate that the distribution of the compared entities are similar?

I encountered the idea here:
https://github.com/yuta-hi/pytorch_similarity

but I am having a hard time understanding the equation ...

Comment: Where did you encounter it? Can you give a reference? [is it this](https://www.google.com/search?q=gradient+correlation%3F&oq=gradient+correlation%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.6932j0j7&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: The formula in your github link, called there the "the normalized cross correlation," is the formula for Pearson's correlation coefficient.